# Using onEdit Function Creating Calendar Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-calendar-api

I thing I'm really close here but for whatever reason this isn't generating a calendar event for me. This is based on the createEvent function from the following link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar. I'm using a test sheet at the moment with the following [spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE26L.png)

I intend for the `onEdit` function to notify the user that a calendar event has been created when the checkbox in column 9 is selected, then call the `createEvent` function based on parameters corresponding to values retrieved from the same row as the selected checkbox.

```
/**
 * Creates an event in the user's default calendar.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var desc = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
    var dateVal1 = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2).getValue();
    var dateVal2 = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3).getValue();
    var timeVal1 = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).getValue();
    var timeVal2 = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).getValue();
    var emailAddress = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).getValue();

    var month = Number(dateVal1.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = dateVal1.getDate();

    // console.log(month)

    var monthname = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    e.source.toast("Calendar Event Created for " + monthname[month-1] + " " + day);

    createEvent(desc, dateVal1, dateVal2, timeVal1, timeVal2, emailAddress);
  }
}

function createEvent(summ, dateValue1, dateValue2, timeValue1, timeValue2, email) {
  const calendarId = 'primary';

  // event details for creating event.

  var mo = dateValue1.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayofmo = dateValue1.getDate();
  var year1 = dateValue1.getYear() + 1900;

  var mo2 = dateValue2.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayofmo2 = dateValue2.getDate();
  var year2 = dateValue2.getYear() + 1900;

  const start = getSheetDate(mo, dayofmo, year1, timeValue1, timeValue1);
  const end = getSheetDate(mo2, dayofmo2, year2, timeValue2, timeValue2);

  let event = {
    summary: summ,
    location: 'The Office',
    description: 'Meeting regarding ...',
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: email.toString()}
    ],
    };
    try {
      // call method to insert/create new event in provided calandar
      event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
      Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.id);
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
    }
}

function getSheetDate(day, month, year, hour, minutes) {
  const date = new Date();

  // console.log(date.getDate())

  date.setDate(month, day, year);
  var hourstring = String(hour);
  var ampm = hourstring.split(" ")[1];
  var hournum = Number(hourstring.split(":")[0]);

  // console.log(hournum);

  // console.log(ampm);

  if (ampm == 'P' && hournum < 12) {
    hournum = (hournum + 12);
    date.setHours(hournum);
  }

  date.setHours(hournum);

  // console.log(hournum);

  var minutesstring = String(minutes);
  var minutesnum = String(minutesstring.split(":")[1]);
  var minutesnum2 = Number(minutesnum.split(" ")[0]);
  date.setMinutes(minutesnum2);

  // console.log(minutesnum2);

  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  return date;
}
```

Currently the `onEdit` function notifies the user when a checkbox is selected. For example, in the given spreadsheet example, when a checkbox is selected it will say 'Calendar Event Created for December 13.'

Previously the `createEvent` function had no parameters and I had established variables that directly pulled the description, date, time, etc. from specific cells. This created calendar events flawlessly but then I had to exclusively reference these set cells which I don't want. I attempted the above and tried to create parameters within the `createEvent` function that could draw from the variables defined in that `onEdit` function.

Here is an example of the `creatEvent` function that worked like a charm, I just need this to function when I edit that checkbox cell.

```
function createEvent() {
  const calendarId = 'primary';

  // event details for creating event.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var summ = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var dateValue1 = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var dateValue2 = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var timeValue1 = sheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  var timeValue2 = sheet.getRange('E2').getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange('F2').getValue();

  var mo = dateValue1.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayofmo = dateValue1.getDate();
  var year1 = dateValue1.getYear() + 1900;

  var mo2 = dateValue2.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayofmo2 = dateValue2.getDate();
  var year2 = dateValue2.getYear() + 1900;

  const start = getSheetDate(mo, dayofmo, year1, timeValue1, timeValue1);
  const end = getSheetDate(mo2, dayofmo2, year2, timeValue2, timeValue2);

  let event = {
    summary: summ,
    location: 'The Office',
    description: 'Meeting regarding ...',
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: email.toString()}
    ],
    };
    try {
      // call method to insert/create new event in provided calandar
      event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
      Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.id);
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
    }
}
```

Could this maybe have something to do with how I'm getting the spreadsheet? (`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` vs. `e.range.getSheet()`)

SOLUTION:

Here is a functioning solution using an installable trigger thanks to onit, Cooper and doubleunary!

```
/**
 * Creates an event in the user's default calendar.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert
 */
function installableOnEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const [summ, dateValue1, dateValue2, timeValue1, timeValue2, email] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0];
  if (e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.value == "TRUE") {

    var month = Number(dateValue1.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = dateValue1.getDate();

    // console.log(month)

    var monthname = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    e.source.toast("Calendar Event Created for " + monthname[month-1] + " " + day);

    const calendarId = 'primary';

    // event details for creating event.

    var mo = dateValue1.getMonth() + 1;
    var dayofmo = dateValue1.getDate();
    var year1 = dateValue1.getFullYear();

    var mo2 = dateValue2.getMonth() + 1;
    var dayofmo2 = dateValue2.getDate();
    var year2 = dateValue2.getFullYear();

    const start = getSheetDate(mo, dayofmo, year1, timeValue1, timeValue1);
    const end = getSheetDate(mo2, dayofmo2, year2, timeValue2, timeValue2);

    let event = {
      summary: summ,
      location: 'The Office',
      description: 'Meeting regarding ...',
      start: {
        dateTime: start.toISOString()
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: end.toISOString()
      },
      attendees: [
        {email: email.toString()}
      ],
      };
      try {
        // call method to insert/create new event in provided calandar
        event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
      } catch (err) {
      Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to get a new Date object relative to the current date.
 * @param {number} daysOffset The number of days in the future for the new date.
 * @param {number} hour The hour of the day for the new date, in the time zone
 *     of the script.
 * @return {Date} The new date.
 */
function getSheetDate(day, month, year, hour, minutes) {
  const date = new Date();

  // console.log(date.getDate())

  date.setDate(month, day, year);
  var hourstring = String(hour);
  var ampm = hourstring.split(" ")[1];
  var hournum = Number(hourstring.split(":")[0]);

  // console.log(hournum);

  // console.log(ampm);

  if (ampm == 'P' && hournum < 12) {
    hournum = (hournum + 12);
    date.setHours(hournum);
  }

  date.setHours(hournum);

  // console.log(hournum);

  var minutesstring = String(minutes);
  var minutesnum = String(minutesstring.split(":")[1]);
  var minutesnum2 = Number(minutesnum.split(" ")[0]);
  date.setMinutes(minutesnum2);

  // console.log(minutesnum2);

  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Hi! (Not tested), but you could try changing the `onEdit()` to another name, run it once from the script editor, so that permissions are given and set an Installable Trigger on edit basis, using the newly renamed function. I haven't tested it, but `onEdit` does have some limitations VS when you do it via installable trigger with explicit authorization may solve this type of problem.

Comment: Simple Triggers can only run functions that complete in less than 30 seconds

Comment: 6 of your first seven assignments can be done all in one line and will save a lot of time

Comment: Leaving Logger.log() in your final onEdit() code just wastes time.

Comment: If you wish this to run at it's fastest then don't break it up into separate functions.

Comment: Thank you onit & Cooper for your feedback. Looking into installable triggers but I don't know if that's a desirable route because a variety of users will be using this and to my understanding regardless of the user, these triggers will be coming from me. Correct me if I'm wrong. @Cooper, I removed Logger.log(), replaced the OnEdit variables with 'const [summ, dateValue1, dateValue2, timeValue1, timeValue2, email] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0];' and combined the functions onEdit and createEvent (now just onEdit). I'm still getting the same result. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and thus cannot call functions that require authorization, such as `Calendar.Events.insert()`.

To make it work, rename `onEdit(e)` to something like `installableOnEdit(e)` and run it through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). You will be asked to authorize the function when you create the trigger. The function will run under the account that created the trigger, and all events will get created in that account's calendar.

> `var year1 = dateValue1.getYear() + 1900;`

You may want to use `Date.getFullYear()` instead of `Date.getYear()`.

Comment: Hi @doubleunary - Thank you again for this, very helpful, I'm so glad this is functioning now. I'm curious if you may know how to solve a separate question regarding this same topic. Currently when I generate a calendar event with an email address that is not my associated gmail, an .ics attachment is sent to that email from my gmail. However, if another user of the spreadsheet tries to use a non-google email, the script fails, however other users can add calendar events to their own gmail using this trigger.

Comment: Since I am the owner of the spreadsheet (I presume), any event generated is coming from my gmail. Which I assume emails are not sent to other recipients by other users because they are not authorized to send emails from my gmail account. If you think there is a separate reason for this let me know. However, if that is the issue, is there a way to bypass this so other users of the spreadsheet can send calendar events to others, or is there a way that events can be inserted via the editing user of the spreadsheet? Let me know if I can clear any of that up, sorry that was lengthy.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).